# Does the podcast tag have a meaning I'm not aware of?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

While looking for the great old question that lists good podcasts I saw several questions tagged with the podcast tag that have (as far as I can tell) nothing to do with podcasts.

[Have you ever restricted yourself to using a subset of language features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867857/have-you-ever-restricted-yourself-to-using-a-subset-of-language-features)

[Large switch statements bad OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505454/large-switch-statements-bad-oop)

Is there some meaning to the tag which I'm missing, or are these questions simply mistagged?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that those topics were discussed on the Stack Overflow podcast.  If that's the case, then the tag probably seemed relevant at the time, but the connection has since faded.